# Query syntax exception in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, hbm

MisRecords.java

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="dat_emprecords")
    public class MisRecords {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="pk_EmpRec_Idx")
        int id;
        @Column(name="EmpRec_EmpFName")
        String firstName;
        @Column(name="EmpRec_EmpLName")
        String lastName;
        @Column(name="fk_EmpRec_EmpID")
        int empId;
        @Column(name="fk_emprec_empreportingmgrid")
        int empReportingManagerId;
        // setters and getters
```

Test.java

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Session session=new  AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
 Query query=session.createQuery("from MisRecords");
    List<MisRecords> list=query.list();{
    for(MisRecords employee:list){
          System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
     }
 }
}    
}
```

I am trying to map an existing database using hibernate but I get this exception, please help.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MisRecords is not mapped
>   [from MisRecords]

Comment: Either the entity is not listed in the Hibernate configuration file, or it's not annotated with the correct Entity annotation (javax.persistence.Entity).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to add a mapping in the hibernate configuration for your *MisRecords*.

### Variant a) hibernate.cfg.xml with separate mapping file:

If you have configured your hibernate context manually by hibernate.cfg.xml you have add your mapping in that file as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- Default Database Dialect in Hibernate -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!--  Schema -->
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">YOUR_DB_SCHEME</property>

        ...

        <!-- Your mapping for your model goes after -->
        <mapping class="coolproject.modelpackage.ModelEntity1"/>
        <mapping class="coolproject.modelpackage.ModelEntity2"/>
        <mapping class="coolproject.modelpackage.ModelEntity3"/>
        <mapping class="coolproject.modelpackage.ModelEntity4"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

### Variant b) Spring ORM with JPA

If you have a spring web framework context running, you could enable automated scanning for @Entity classes by configuring an entity manager factory in a spring persistence configuration bean:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    ...

    /**
     * EntityManager Factory Bean
     * 
     * @return
     *      {@link LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean}
     */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());

        // add base packages containing @Entity annotated classes here
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "packages", "to.scan", "for.Entity.annotated.classes" });

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    ...

}
```

cheers,
ceth